# Xamarian deploying to device

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have never deployed an app for texting in a real iOS device, only on an iPhone 7 plus simulator. I've watched some tutorials on how to do it and this is what I have done so far.

I have made an iOS Development Certificate. I made an App id, connected a device and entered the UDID. Then created a new device and at last I have made a Provisioning Profile with the iPhone 7 Device connected. The iOS development certificate connected and the App ID connected. After I did all of that, I continued to watch all the tutorials but there seems to be a change which I can't figure out.

[image: View Detail Button]

As you can see, in the picture above there is a view detail button which you click then download your Provisioning Profile to your XCode, but for me there is no View Detail button. Instead it looks something like this.

[image: No View Detail]

So unfortunately, I don't know what to do from here. I tried going to Xcode > Window > Devices then right clicked on my device then it looks something like this.

[image: Xcode Windows Devices]

So I click Show Provisioning Profiles, press "add" then add my Provisioning Profile. The next thing I did was go back to Xamarian went to info.plist, double clicked it and then entered my Bundle Identifier.

[image]

Then right clicked the 2 Calculator file, went down to Options and then set everything up, as you could see in the picture. Then I press run but it doesn't seem to work

[image: Option settings]

This error message comes up:

[image: Error Message]

I am pretty sure I have done everything right, but there seems to still be an error. The only possible bit I think may have gone wrong is when there wasn't the "view detail" button, so I did it a another way. Maybe the problem is I downloaded the Provisioning Profile on the iOS Device, but not in the Xcode mac or something?

I don't have a clue what I did wrong and have tried everything about 5 times but it still didn't work. It will be great if someone could help.

These are all the Certificate and stuff I did in the App development section.

[image] 
[image] 
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not enough reputation to comment, so I am going to take a shot in the dark here. My question to you is, did you download the certificate to your MacBook before or after you added your mobile device to it? Your Mac has to know of which devices you have allowed to develop on, so you need to make sure your .mobileprovision on your Mac has that UDID in it.

You can check if your .mobileprovision is added by looking in "~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles" and sorting by "Date Modified" to see if you have a fresh one updating after you downloaded it from [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com). Xcode will assign a GUID to the name so the provisioning profile will not have the name displaying on the website.

Also, the error possibly looks certificate related. Is the certificate valid and trusted in your keychain? I noticed no mention of adding the certificate to the "Keychain Access" application.

Comment: i download the certificate first thing then trust it on keychain. After that i made all of the other things such as the App ID and the Provisiong Profile.

Comment: The problem i did have was i couldn't find the view detail button on xcode preference so this might be why i wasn't able to download the provision profile to x code and that might be why it is not working. I know i have downloaded it on my computer but do i have to download it on xcode as well and if so, how do i do it.

Comment: It is actually way easier than it seems. When you double click the .mobileprovision file that comes from the apple developer site, the default program used is Xcode. It will look like nothing happens, but in the directory I linked above you will see a file update within the directory. It should have a modified time stamp of the exact time you clicked the downloaded .mobileprovision, that is usually how I determine if it added properly.

Comment: Where is the .mobileprovision file, could you guide me to this. I right now get an error saying replacing existing signature. Could you then tell me how i could fix this issue and what this issue actually means

Comment: Sure, if you look down at the very bottom of your images, there is one that shows a `Hoippy Calculator Provisioning Profile` with a status of `Active`. All you need to do is click on that provisioning profile to see a dropdown and then click `Download`. You may want to double check that the provisioning profile has a similar App ID to your application, which is shown on that dropdown. I.E. it should say `com.hoippy.calculator.*`, `com.hoippy.*` or even just a `*`. Once it is completed, just double click it in your browser's `Downloads`.

Comment: That is great help, i think i am getting there. Now i am getting a final error saying error: 0xe8008016. This was the error message Calculator.app' on the device 'Anamu ': Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016). It will be great if you could help me fix this as well >< Thx so much for everything so far